# v-autocomplete woes in Vuetifyjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Im working with `<v-autocomplete>` and it seems a little inflexible in terms of customization. Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Are we able to have a default display text value in the input when the page loads for `<v-autocomplete>`? For example:

I have a value in my items[] array, or any other `data()` value, and when the page loads I want one of those items to show by default (display text). Can I have it so it shows on component mounted() ? I've tried binding a value to the v-model but it will only set the value, the display text is empty.

vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/autocompletes#asynchronous-items

In the example above, the states[] array has bunch of values. Can we set one of them to show up as a default selection on mount/render?
I'm coming from React so forgive my inexperience! I'm still getting the hang of Vue and Vuetify

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like that:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div style="padding: 20px">
      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="state"
        :items="states"
        :filter="customFilter"
        return-object
        color="white"
        item-text="name"
        label="State"
      ></v-autocomplete>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 20px;">state selected = {{ state }}</div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({
    state: null,
    states: [
      { name: 'Florida', id: 1 },
      { name: 'Georgia', id: 2 },
      { name: 'Nebraska', id: 3 },
      { name: 'California', id: 4 },
      { name: 'New York', id: 5 },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    customFilter(item, queryText, itemText) {
      const text = item.name.toLowerCase();
      const searchText = queryText.toLowerCase();
      return text.indexOf(searchText) > -1;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    [this.state] = this.states;
  },
};
</script>
```

In this example, I use `v-autocomplete` with prop `return-object` for handle `this.state` (variable in v-model).

If you don't use `return-object`, you must do that way:

```
  mounted() {
    // [this.state] = this.states;
    this.state = 'Florida';
  },
```

Because in prop `item-text` was defined `name`

Comment: yes, that was it! I didn't use return-object which was causing the issues. thank you